# Installed in wrong path and want to uninstall

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

I wanted to install **Maple software** (licensed software and not available in software center) by running `Maple13LinuxX86_64Installer.bin` and which led me path preference and I accidentally installed in `/usr/local` but correct path will  be `/usr/local/maple`. Please help me to uninstall it because there is other software in the same location.

Here is the result of `sudo ls -ltr /usr/local`

```
total 908
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug  5  2015 src
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug  5  2015 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug  5  2015 include
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug  5  2015 games
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Mar 12  2016 man -> share/man
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Mar 12  2016 Wolfram
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Apr  7  2016 texlive
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root   4096 Apr  8  2016 share
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Nov 17 11:28 MATLAB
drwxrwxr-x  4 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:17 jre.X86_64_LINUX
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:17 afm
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 data
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 examples
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 examplesclassic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 etc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 extern
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 java
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 test
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 samples
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 X11_defaults
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 toolbox
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  11071 Mar 10 15:18 readme.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 530188 Mar 10 15:18 Install.html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 133254 Mar 10 15:18 EULA.html
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:18 bin.X86_64_LINUX
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 139665 Mar 10 15:18 Maple_13_InstallLog.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Mar 10 15:21 license
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  12288 Mar 10 15:23 bin
```

From the result which I have understand that the software was installed in `March-10 15:18`. Should I delete those folders? What should I do?

Here is the 
[Mple 13 log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7RcU8nqsqI6Zkd5RzQyeTVTUUk)

Comment: The screenshot isn't very useful. Please [edit] your question and i) replace the screenshot with the output of running `ls -ltr /usr/local` in a terminal. Use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to make it look like code. ii) explain how you installed maple. What commands did you run? iii) Explain why you didn't install `maple` from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: OK, this is more complicated than I hoped. As you can see, there are many directoris there that were modified at `Mar 10 15:18`, the day and time you installed Maple. You can't just delete them because some are system directories, like `/usr/local/lib`. So, you can either try to find the list of files that were modified between 15:18 and 15:23 on Mar 10 or, if you're lucky, the `Maple_13_InstallLog.log` logfile will contain a list of all files installed. So, please [edit] your question and show us the contents of `Maple_13_InstallLog.log`.